# Z-index is not stacking

Tags: html, css, sass

I have been trying around for so long, and have read a number of articles and I still don't get it! I am trying got move that little icon to the left of the header, but for some reason its stacking below the parent element!

this is my css:

```css
        .step__content {
            margin-top: 120px;
            position: relative;

            div.ui-accordion-header {
                margin-left: 30px;

                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    height: 20px;
                    width: 20px;
                    left: -7px;
                    background-image: url('../images/i.svg');
                    z-index: 100;
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the html: 
[image]

the first :after element is the icon!

here is an image:

[image]

I want the icon to be at the left of the header! But as I push it left it goes below? The complete image of the icon is not visible because half is underneath!

Comment: Please include HTML in your js fiddle

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stacking below the parent element"? Looking at your example image, the icon is clearly "above" the text in terms a z-index (part of the "A" is hidden by the icon color) and the icon is "above" the text in terms of vertical layout

Comment: @Vlad274 Yes that is fine, its above the text! As I push it left it moves below under .step__content! I have added a different image, maybe that makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

I think what is actually happening is the pseudo element is just going outside of an `overflow: hidden;` element...

This works for me (even if you remove the z-index styles). 
As you can see the psuedo element is over the text. Try changing the :after z-index to -5 and it goes below.

```css
.step__content {
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-accordion-header {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-accordion-header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -20px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="step__content">
  <div class="ui-accordion-header">
    <p>Headers</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use before pseudo element instead.

```
  .step__content {
            margin-top: 120px;
            position: relative;

            div.ui-accordion-header {
                margin-left: 30px;

                &::before {
                    content: 'testing';
                    height: 20px;
                    width: 20px;
                    z-index: 100;

                }
            }
        }
```

```
<div class="step__content">

<section class="ce_accordionStart ce_accordino block">
  <div id="ui-id-1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active">

  <span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
    Header
  </span>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```